# Compiling QGIS for Slackware (Slak 14)?

Tags: qgis, compile

I use a Slak 14 box and tried to install QGIS on it. the compile process goes on for 30 minutes or so (dual Xeon 3.2 ghz) and then I get the errors below. Says the compiler doesn't work. Have had no other problem with this compiler. Anybody able to point me in a direction? I'm kinda not sure which way to pursue this.The one thing strikes me is that it cmake isn't acting well.

---

...many minutes of output.

> qgis-2.4.0/tests/testdata/zonalstatistics/polys.cpg
>   qgis-2.4.0/tests/testdata/zonalstatistics/polys.dbf
>   qgis-2.4.0/tests/testdata/zonalstatistics/polys.prj
>   qgis-2.4.0/tests/testdata/zonalstatistics/polys.qpj
>   qgis-2.4.0/tests/testdata/zonalstatistics/polys.shp
>   qgis-2.4.0/tests/testdata/zonalstatistics/polys.shx
>   qgis-2.4.0/tools/
>   qgis-2.4.0/tools/qgis-qt3to4.pl
>   qgis-2.4.0/tools/qgis_config/
>   qgis-2.4.0/tools/qgis_config/qgis_config.cpp
>   qgis-2.4.0/tools/qgisdetect.m4
>   -- The C compiler identification is unknown
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
>   CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
>     The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

> Change Dir: /tmp/jah/qgis-2.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:/usr/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec2321741014/fast"
>
> /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2321741014.dir/build.make
>     CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2321741014.dir/build
>
> gmake[1]: Entering directory
>     `/tmp/jah/qgis-2.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report
>     /tmp/jah/qgis-2.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
>
> Building C object
>     CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2321741014.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
>
> /usr/bin/cc -O2 -march=i486 -mtune=i686 -o
>     CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2321741014.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
>     /tmp/jah/qgis-2.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
>
> /tmp/jah/qgis-2.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c:1:0: error:
>     CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
>
> #ifdef __cplusplus
>      ^
>
> gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/jah/qgis-2.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2321741014.dir/testCCompiler.c.o]
>     Error 1
>
> gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec2321741014/fast] Error 2
>
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:7 (PROJECT)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/tmp/jah/qgis-2.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also "/tmp/jah/qgis-2.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
>   Cannot install /tmp/qgis-2.4.0-i486-1-jah.txz:  file not found
>
> Installation complete
>
> bash-4.2#